# keyboardWasShown is working, but NSNotification is null

Tags: ios, null, nsnotifications

I am trying to move the keyboard, but I can't seem to get a value from notification below is my code and the log:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]     CGRectValue].size;
    NSLog(@"info dictionary %@", info);
    NSLog(@"keyboard height: %f", keyboardSize.height);
```

log:

```
2013-06-19 15:03:37.777 DepreciationDraft[5822:c07] info dictionary (null)
2013-06-19 15:03:37.777 DepreciationDraft[5822:c07] keyboard height: 0.000000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are you trying to do with the keyboard?

Comment: How do you register for the notification ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss the keyboard, just do:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: And if the keyboard is presented from another view that is not in `self.view`? Also `keyboardWasShown` is not for dismissing, it's for showing and I think the user maybe is trying to move up the content of the view when the keyboard appears.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of unsure of what he was exactly asking.

Answer (score 0):

danypata's comment helped to answer the question.

When I added an observer to the NSNotification Center, I used UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification instead of UIKeyboardDidShowNotification.

I don't know why I even used UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification in the first place.